# How can I integrate Fancybox 3 in Wordpress properly

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, lightbox

I would like to integrate Facybox 3 in my WordPress (only on posts). It works but I'm a bit bothered cuz the initialize script is loaded after the core minified `fancybox js`. So, here is the code I added in my child `functions.php`:

```
// ENQUEUE FANCYBOX SCRIPT
function fancy_scripts() {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox-script', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js', array(), '3.3.5', true );     
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fancy_scripts' );

// INITIALIZE
function fancy_init(){
    if ( is_single() ) {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
            buttons: [
            'zoom',
            'fullScreen',
            'share',
            'thumbs',
            'close'
            ],
            protect: true
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.fancybox-share a.fancybox-share__button', function(e){ 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer','fancy_init')
;
// ENQUEUE CSS TO FOOTER
function fancy_footer_styles() {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'fancybox-style','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css' );
    }   
};
add_action( 'get_footer', 'fancy_footer_styles' );
```

And here is the output html

```
<!--FOOTER-->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
        buttons: [
        'zoom',
        'fullScreen',
        'share',
        'thumbs',
        'close'
        ],
        protect: true
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.fancybox-share a.fancybox-share__button', function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    });
});
</script>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='fancybox-style-css'  href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css?ver=81a38b5eb2a4df901367646a93448a94' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js?ver=3.3.5'></script>
```

My questions are:

1. Is it a problem that Initialize loads before the core fancy js?
2. Is it a proper way to do that or do I absolutely have to put the initialize script in a separate js file and then enqueue it in the same function where I load the core file? As this, I mean :

.

```
function fancy_scripts() {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox-script', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js', array(), '3.3.5', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), true );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fancy_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no real problems doing it this manner, but there is a more correct way, namely using [`wp_add_inline_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/), which is exactly meant for situations where you want to append something to a script file. You would use it like this:

```
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse302588_enqueue_add_script');

function wpse302588_enqueue_add_script() {
  $add_script = "jQuery(document).ready(function($){ .... });"; // your script as a string without <script> tags
  wp_enqueue_script ('fancybox-script', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js', array(), '3.3.5', true);     
  wp_add_inline_script ('fancybox-script', $add_script, 'after');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to cjbj, here is the working code to add Fancybox to Wordpress:

```
// ADD FANCYBOX SCRIPT
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_fancybox_script');
function add_fancybox_script() {
    if ( is_single() ) { // LOAD ONLY FOR SINGLE POSTS
        $add_script = 'jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
            $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
                buttons: [
                "zoom",
                "fullScreen",
                "share",
                "thumbs",
                "close"
                ],
                protect: true
            });
        });'; 
        wp_enqueue_script ('fancybox-script', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js', array(), '3.3.5', true);     
        wp_add_inline_script ('fancybox-script', $add_script, 'after');
    }
}
// ENQUEUE CSS TO FOOTER
function fancy_footer_styles() {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'fancybox-style','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.3.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css' );
    }   
};
add_action( 'get_footer', 'fancy_footer_styles' );
```

I've loaded the css in the footer as it is not important when the page load.

Also, be careful about mixing simple quotes (') and double quotes(")!